# How do I run clean from qmake?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

How do I run clean (as right click on my project name -> clean) from `qmake`? Is a binary utility that does the clean? I'd like to run this on release, somethig like:

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release): clean project
```

Comment: Running qmake creates a Makefile containing the rules for the clean target.

Answer (score 1):

I had worked on [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) vizkit widgets for Robotics Construction Kit (ROCK) software.

When I need to clean the project from the terminal, I go to the build folder and I use this command:

```
make clean
```